# Chrome Dev Tools - Start debugging by function name

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to specify the debugger for listening for specific method names? Example: When the function `myFunc` get called, I want to start debugging. Yes, I know that this seems strange, but in some projects I don't know the name of the javascript file to start the debugging, but I do know the name of the method.

It would be something like the Event Listener Breakpoints, but with an arbitrary method name instead an event name.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the function, try `debugger;`

Comment: You can set breakpoints on lines inside the function that gets called.

Comment: @elclanrs: To do that, he'd have to know what file it was in.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Well he can debug it to find out, oh the irony. If the function is anonymous and minified, good luck with that

Comment: @elclanrs I am starting to wonder if you actually read the OP's question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the function name with a search and set the break point. You can use the following key combination to search accross the files.

- Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- OSX:  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yeah. Fairly sure the literal answer to the OP's question is "no" and this is the best workaround. If the function is defined by a function declaration or named function expression, you can type `tion foo` when looking for `function foo`, to avoid hitting everywhere it's *used*. (That won't help with anonymous function expressions, of course.)

Comment: It's indeed not the exactly answer for my question, but it's more than enough for my usecase, with that I solve the problem of debugging some generated JS files that are hard to trace in the project source.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to add another method that I came across today while searching, you can open the JS console and use `debug(Some.path.to.myFunc)` and it will set a debug breakpoint on the function. Use `undebug(func)` to unset it. You can also use `monitor(func)` and `unmonitor(func)` to get a console log when that function is called. Learned about these from: https://amasad.me/debugging

Comment: You can find the official documentation for these commands and more at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/api and https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities